# LinqToSql Queries instead of some SQL query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

```
SELECT * FROM register WHERE user_id LIKE 'a%'

SELECT * FROM register WHERE user_id LIKE '%m'

SELECT * FROM register WHERE user_id LIKE '%andru%'


SELECT R.name,C.country_name,S.state_name 
FROM register R JOIN country C ON R.country_id=C.country_id
JOIN state S  ON R.state_id=S.state_id

SELECT R.name,C.country_name,S.state_name 
FROM register R INNER JOIN country C ON R.country_id=C.country_id       
INNER JOIN state S ON R.state_id=S.state_id
```

Now i need **LinqToSql** Queries instead of these query

Comment: [whathaveyoutried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Agreed, and I like the link

Comment: Stabbing in the dark: Take a look at [`SqlMethods.Like`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = context.Registers.Select(x => x.StartsWith(foo)).ToList();

result = context.Registers.Select(x => x.EndsWith(foo)).ToList();

result = context.Registers.Select(x => x.Contains(foo)).ToList();

result = from register in context.Registers
         join state in context.States on register.state_id equals state.state_id
         select new { register.name, state.country_name, state.state_name }
```

---

Note, `inner join` and `join` function the same in `SQL` — thus no need to complicate.